# Install Addons in Headless Blender

Tags: python, add-on, command-line

Is it possible to install a Blender addon in headless mode? I need the ability to export gltfs from a Ubuntu server instance and the only instructions I can find for installing an addon in Blender is through the GUI.

Is there a command line argument? Or is it possible to unzip the addon somewhere that will work with Blender?

Comment: You should be able to install by unzipping into `Blender\2.##\scripts\addons`, though you still need to activate it to be able to use it.

Comment: Update: since Blender 2.8 the call moved to: ```
bpy.ops.preferences.addon_install(...)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just unzip the add-on into the `/2.7x/scripts/addons/` directory. On Linux, it should be in the same directory as Blender. If there is more than just a single Python script, make sure to put the whole unzipped folder in, not just its contents.

To enable the add-on, you'll need to swap out the user preferences `.blend` file, found at `/2.7x/config/userpref.blend`. On a computer with a GUI, install and enable the add-on, and any other add-ons you want to use. Save the user preferences, and then copy the `userpref.blend` file to the appropriate spot on the Linux server.

Answer (score 22):

Using python you can install an addon with [`bpy.ops.wm.addon_install()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.ops.wm.html#bpy.ops.wm.addon_install), you can then enable the addon with `bpy.ops.wm.addon_enable()` and disable it with `bpy.ops.wm.addon_disable()`. To keep the addon enabled every time you start blender you save your settings with `bpy.ops.wm.save_userpref()`

For `addon_install` you give it the filepath to the addon, this is the same file you would choose if you were using [blender's GUI](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/preferences/addons.html#header).

To enable or disable an addon you need to specify the module name, that is the folder name installed into the addons folder or the filename without `.py` for single file addons.

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.wm.addon_install(filepath='/home/shane/Downloads/testaddon.py')
bpy.ops.wm.addon_enable(module='testaddon')
bpy.ops.wm.save_userpref()
```

There are two ways you can make this work remotely through the CLI.

Save the steps in a script and run it.

```
blender -b -P enableaddon.py
```

Start blender as a python console and type each in directly.

```
blender -b --python-console
Python 3.5.2 <snip...>
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> import bpy
>>> bpy.ops.wm.addon_install(filepath='/home/shane/Downloads/testaddon.py')
>>> bpy.ops.wm.addon_enable(module='testaddon')
>>> bpy.ops.wm.save_userpref()
```

Note: For Blender 2.80+, things are slightly different:

```
>>> import bpy
>>> bpy.ops.preferences.addon_install(filepath='/home/shane/Downloads/testaddon.py')
>>> bpy.ops.preferences.addon_enable(module='testaddon')
>>> bpy.ops.wm.save_userpref()
```

Use <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to exit the python console and quit blender.

Comment: I compiled blender as a python module and I got the install to work with your script - however the settings will be gone whenever I reload the script.

Any clues on how to change this?

Comment: I'm not sure if bpy as a module will read a startup.blend. Check the [preference locations](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/getting_started/installing/configuration/directories.html) to see if one gets saved into place. Worst case is to use a script to adjust settings before doing the task you want.

Comment: @sambler I have compiled Blender as a Python3 module so I don't have access to the GUI. I am installing an addon and enable it using the bpy module. I then save the user preferences using bpy.ops.wm.save_userpref() and exit Python. Next time that I do import bpy I don't see the addon API being added to the bpy module.Do you know how I can fix that?If I run the same exact script in Blender terminal (when using the GUI) everything works fine.(You may answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118584/why-the-addon-installation-succeeds-but-the-api-is-not-accessible-through-the-bp))

Answer (score 1):

Try the `overwrite=True` option, as shown below. Also please note that for directories, you will need to pass the zipped file:

```
bpy.ops.wm.addon_install(overwrite=True, filepath="module_dir.zip")
```

Also when using CLI, you may need to pass -y option to enable automatic Python script execution

```
blender -b  -y  --python ebableaddon.py  my_blend_file.blend -o output_file -a
```