# Why the addon installation succeeds but the API is not accessible through the bpy module?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, installation, armory

I have compiled Blender 2.79b as a Python3 module on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I install an addon using `bpy.ops.wm.addon_install()`, enable it using `bpy.ops.wm.addon_enable(module='packageName)` and save the user preferences using `bpy.ops.wm.save_userpref()`. However, after I open Python3 again and do import bpy I cannot see the addon API's being added to the bpy module. If I run the same exact "addon installation" script when using Blender with the GUI everything works fine, but not when I have compiled Blender as a Python module. So I wonder, does anyone know whether I'm doing something wrong and how I can fix this?

In case you're wondering, I am trying to install [Armory](https://armory3d.org/manual/#/getting_started/setup?id=using-armory-as-add-on) addon and below is the script I used to do the installation:

**installArmory.sh**

```
wget -O armsdk.zip https://www.dropbox.com/s/a17prr2hzsjkfog/armsdk.zip?dl=1
python3 installArmory.py
```

**installArmory.py**

```
import bpy, os, zipfile

with zipfile.ZipFile("armsdk.zip","r") as zip_ref:
    zip_ref.extractall(os.getcwd() + '/')

# Install the addon
bpy.ops.wm.addon_install(filepath=os.getcwd() + '/armsdk/armory/blender/addon/armory.py')
bpy.ops.wm.addon_enable(module='armory')

# Set the SDK path
user_prefs = bpy.context.user_preferences
addon_prefs = user_prefs.addons['armory'].preferences
addon_prefs.sdk_path = os.getcwd() + '/armsdk'

bpy.ops.wm.save_userpref()
```

Comment: I don't believe loading the bpy module will read the startup file that has the enabled addons saved. Look at the length of `user_prefs.addons` before and after calling `bpy.ops.wm.read_homefile()`. That would mean opening a blend after read_homefile or enable addons each time you start python and import bpy.

Comment: @sambler I think I found a [temporary] solution to this problem. See my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I could find a way around this but I don't think this will work for all addons that require restarting Blender, but it works for [Armory](http://armory3d.org/).

Here are the steps:

```
# Install the addon
bpy.ops.wm.addon_install(filepath=os.getcwd() + '/armsdk/armory/blender/addon/armory.py')
bpy.ops.wm.addon_enable(module='armory')

# Set the SDK path (Armory-specific)
user_prefs = bpy.context.user_preferences
addon_prefs = user_prefs.addons['armory'].preferences
addon_prefs.sdk_path = os.getcwd() + '/armsdk'

# Use the `start()` function of `bpy.ops.arm_addon` to enable it.
bpy.ops.arm_addon.start()
```

Now `arm` shows up in `bpy.ops`. I don't think all addons have a function like `start()` that Armory has.